# R Shiny Leaflet Map won't redraw after the first movement

Tags: dictionary, shiny, leaflet

I have been working on my first little project in R and have run into an issue with a Leaflet map. It will render properly with the data and design I have specified thus far, but once I move the map in browser or the R viewer in RStudio it will no longer react to clicks/drags/etc. and will not react even if it is left alone for several minutes.

I have also had an issue with the zoom functionality, I am not sure if this is due to something that I missed or something to do with the above issue.

Example of the data:
[Data_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THTwk.png)

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------

library("shiny") 
library("tidyverse")
library("leaflet")
library("leaflet.minicharts")

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Wiersma Sale Iceland Trip"),
   mainPanel(
    leafletOutput(outputId = "Map_1", height = 1080, width = 1920)
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  sheets_data <- read.csv("Iceland_Mark2 - Data.csv")
  output$Map_1 <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet(data = sheets_data) %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addMinicharts(
            sheets_data$Long,
            sheets_data$Lat,
            type = "pie",
            popup = popupArgs(
              labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
              html = paste0(
               "<div>",
               "<h3>",
               sheets_data$Name,
               "</h3>",
                "Description: ",
               sheets_data$Description,
                "<br>",
               "Media_1: ",
               sheets_data$Media_1,
                "</div>"
              )
            )
          )
  })
}

# Run_App -----------------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output:
[Output_of_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Rqi.png)

It needn't be pretty, nor unique, but it does need to react to zooming and movement and I can't for the life of me figure out why it behaves this way.

Comment: The above code is working for me. I'm able to view, zoom-in zoom-out, drag the map along with popups in browser(firefox), R-studio window and R-studio viewer pane without any errors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test it out.  Do you think there may be a hardware issue? I can test on another pc  to see if it works there

Comment: I don't think hardware is the root cause here. Because  I've tested your code both in `Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)` and `Windows 10 (64 bit)` machines. And both machines are equipped with  `3.4.3` version of R. But certainly i couldn't determine why it is not working for you.

Comment: Yeah I tested it on two windows 10 machines and two phones. Unfortunately I can't zoom and once moved it locks into position. Maybe I'll rebuild and see if a minor change solves it. Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem suddenly come up after having already produced a number of maps with no issues. So I figured it most likely was to do with the data I was feeding it.

**I had one row in my chartdata that had NAs. Deleting this row and remapping fixed the problem**.